# Rename file names CAP first character but keep the extention lowercase

Tags: python, file, mp3, rename

I have build a script which renames all the file names in the CWD except the ones the script skips to make all the file names all have a slick and the same format. I build it cause sometimes when you download files or something it's all formatted differently. Some people use".,-_" or upper case everything or w.e. and that's ugly to see plus it's hard to work with so i wrote this script to make everything have one format.

```
import os,sys,re,time

start=time.time()
skip2=['.py']
skip3=['.Jpg','.jpg']
count=0
lijst=os.listdir()

r = re.compile(r'[-_ ]+')
def solve(s):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(s)
    artist, song = name.rsplit('-', 1) 
    artist = r.sub(' ', artist).title().strip()
    song = r.sub(' ', song).title().strip()
    ext = ext.lower()
    return artist + ' - ' + song + ext


for x in lijst:
    if x[-3:] not in skip2 and x[-4:] not in skip3:
        y=x
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            x=solve(x)
            x=re.sub('Ft' ,'Ft.' ,x)
            x=re.sub('Feat' ,'Feat.' ,x)
            x=re.sub('Extended Mix' ,'(Extended Mix)' ,x)
            x=re.sub('Original Mix' ,'(Original Mix)' ,x)
            x=x.replace('(((' ,'(')
            x=x.replace('((' ,'(')
            x=x.replace(')))' ,')')
            x=x.replace('))' ,')')
            x=re.sub("\.\.",".", x)
            x=re.sub('  'or'   ' ,' ' ,x)
            print(x)
            os.rename (y,x)
            count=count+1

print("%s Files edited."%count)

print('It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.')

input("Press enter to exit...")
```

Many thanks to [Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary) I solved my problems and will leave the script on here so other people can use it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to separate filename and extension first and then do some processing on filename and finally join them back:

```
import os
import re

r = re.compile(r'[-_ ]+')
def solve(s):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(s)
    artist, song = name.rsplit('-', 1) 
    artist = r.sub(' ', artist).title().strip()
    song = r.sub(' ', song).title().strip()
    return artist + ' - ' + song + ext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print solve("Alibi- Eternity_ Ft_ Armin Van Buuren and Dj Tiesto_.mp3")
    print solve( "05-orjan_nilsen-so_long_radio__original_mix.mp3")
    print solve( "05 - Orjan Nilsen - So Long Radio (Original Mix).mp3")
```

**Output:**

```
Alibi - Eternity Ft Armin Van Buuren And Dj Tiesto.mp3
05 Orjan Nilsen - So Long Radio Original Mix.mp3
05 Orjan Nilsen - So Long Radio (Original Mix).mp3
```